# Return rvalue reference vs return by value

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's consider the following code:

```
class Test{
public:
Test method(){
Test t; 
return std::move(t);
}

Test&& methoda2(){
Test t; 
return std::move(t);
}
```

What is difference between those methods?

Comment: The second one leads to undefined behaviour because you return a reference to a local variable. The first one works but inhibits copy-elision. `return t;` would be better as this is a move context anyway.